# What will happen in this LASER setup?

Tags: optics, reflection, laser, luminosity

If I have 3 rectangular mirrors, say of dimensions length of 1 meter and width of 0.5 meter and I arrange them in the form of an equilateral triangle, which is of side 0.5 meter.(The mirrors are vertically long)

Now, I place a laser light inside the apparatus, switched on, perfectly horizontally so that the reflected light rays have no reason to get reflected upwards or downwards. (I don't care if they get reflected right or left).

Now, if the setup is in vacuum and the mirrors are perfect reflectors, what will happen here? Will the multiple reflections keep on adding and the energy will build up so very high?

Comment: Yes, this kind or ring resonator has the potential to build up the light intensity so high that it will saturate the laser material or even destroy the laser material or the mirrors. You can do it with two mirrors, too. The ring laser is mostly interesting because it can detect absolute rotation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_laser_gyroscope.

Comment: Lasers have a divergence, so no. Even a laser cavity will have loss mechanisms. And, no mirrors are perfect reflectors.

Comment: @JonCuster: if the gain outweighs the losses, then the cavity will overload. You can keep the gain the same but make the losses arbitrarily small by making the diameter of cavity and laser larger.

Comment: @JonCuster Of course, theoretically they can be made to have zero divergence right? and the mirrors can be perfect too right? or is there any principle of physics that prevents them from being so? (and thank you for your answers )

Comment: No, you can't make a zero divergence laser beam.

Answer (score 2):

Not if the mirrors are flat.  In that case, diffraction would cause the light to diffuse out.  There are no stable configurations.  If the mirrors are curved just right, then you have made a *ring laser*.  [Here's a picture of one](https://www.ion.org/museum/photos/rlg2.JPG).

Comment: How is there diffraction in mirrors? Is it a theoretical requirement or a practical difficulty?

Comment: It's a theoretical issue.  Any beam with a finite cross section has wave vector components perpendicular to the primary direction of propagation, and thus some energy goes in the "wrong" direction.  That's one description of diffraction.  The same is true with concave mirrors, but at each reflection the transverse components are reversed, "correcting" the effect of diffraction.